# How to custom response serialization in Alamofire3

Tags: alamofire

I use Alamofire-beta3, I want to custom response serialization, but I get a error "Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?' "

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7556575/10444657/b0d691fc-719b-11e5-878e-bdd46d03be3b.png

My code is below:

```
public static func objectSerializer <T: MTLModel> () -> ResponseSerializer <T, MTLError>  {

return ResponseSerializer { request, response, data, error in

    // Http Error with Http status code
    guard error == nil else {
        let failureReason = "Network Error"
        let error = MTLError.errorWithCode(error!.code, failureReason: failureReason)
        return .Failure(error)
    }

    // data be null
    guard let validData = data where validData.length > 0 else {
        let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized. Response data was nil or zero length."
        let error = MTLError.errorWithCode(.ResponseDataNull, failureReason: failureReason)
        return .Failure(error)
    }

    do {
        let JSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(validData, options: .AllowFragments)

        // response data is not a obejct json
        guard let json = JSON as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized. Response data is not a obejct JSON"
            let error = MTLError.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializeToObjectFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure(error)
        }

        // Http request successful(state 200 OK), but response data not include `Error Section`
        guard let errorDict = json["error"] as? [String : AnyObject] else {
            let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized. Http request successful(state 200 OK), but response data not include `Error Section`"
            let error = MTLError.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializeErrorSectionFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            return .Failure(error)
        }

        // mean request failed
        if errorDict.count != 0 {

            let error: MTLError!
            do {
                error = try MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(MTLError.self, fromJSONDictionary: errorDict) as! MTLError
            } catch _ {
                let failureReason = "MTLError object serialize failed"
                error = MTLError.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
            }
            return .Failure(error)

        } else {
            // mean request successful
            let dataDict = json["data"] as? [String : AnyObject]

            do {
                let object = try MTLJSONAdapter.modelOfClass(T.self, fromJSONDictionary: dataDict) as! T
                return .Success(object)
            } catch _ {
                let failureReason = "\(T.self) object serialize failed"
                let error = MTLError.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

    } catch _ {
        let failureReason = "Network Error"
        let error = MTLError.errorWithCode(error!.code, failureReason: failureReason)
        return .Failure(error)
    }

}
}


public func responseObject<T: MTLModel> (queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil, willStart: (() -> Void)? = nil, didStop: (() -> Void)? = nil, completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self
{
     willStart?()
     UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

     return response(responseSerializer: Request.objectSerializer(), completionHandler: { (response: Response<T, NSError>) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

             self.printResponse(response)

             dispatch_async(queue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 didStop?()
                 UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                 completionHandler(response)
            }

        })
    })
}
```

I have see https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/817 , but I still don't know how to change my code. Please help me.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I have solved that.Please look at [https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/854](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/854) the answer of **cnoon**.